# Adobe LiveCycle Designer ES4

Tags: adobe, designer, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I am working with one form to which I add a table.
In the first column, I put instructions for the users who need to complete the second column.
Now I need the field in the second column to adjust automatically when the people complete the table in PDF. For the moment, the text is clipped when I put a text more long that the size to the field, and one arrow for move the text in the field). How can I avoid this clipping?

Comment: Are you looking for column width adjustment or field height adjustment?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you you tick `allow multiple lines` from the object palette and set height to `expand to fit` from the layout palette for the text field on the second column.

This will expand the field vertically if the content doesn't fit.